# Wordpress php how to use get_post_gallery_images

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

I have come across the 'get_post_gallery_images' command today and wonder if someone could help explain how to use it.

What I'm trying to achieve is a page which displays all posts and a list of the image urls for each post. So the page should have several posts on, and each post should have several image urls.

Can anyone shed some light on how I would achieve this, is get_post_gallery_images the right command for me to use?

I have something like this so far, but it just returns the word "Array"

```
<?php 

$args = array('posts_per_page'   => 9999); 

$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach($posts as $post) :
$gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post->ID );

echo $gallery;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I hadn't created a way to append the list of images. used this code to insert the urls into a list:

```
$image_list = '<ul>';
foreach( $gallery as $image ) {
    $image_list .= '<li>' . $image . '</li>';
}
$image_list .= '</ul>';
echo $image_list;
```